# problem with bitmask and javascript

Tags: javascript, bitmask

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, but I can't seem to have this simple javascript to work:

```
var a = 0;

a |= (1 << 31);

alert(a);

a |= (1 << 30);

alert(a);
```

you can see it here
http://jsfiddle.net/qPEVk/

shoudln't it 3221225472 ?

thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is technically nothing wrong with that, and a negative number is expected because it's casting to a 32bit signed int.

Basically, the leading bit means "negative or positive", so when you flip it (with `1<<31`) you get a negative number.

Your bitmask will still work exactly like you expect on *up to* 32 bits.  You can't exceed a 32-bit bitmask in JavaScript.

Comment: @Johnathan... check out this post... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908492/unsigned-integer-in-javascript

Comment: but the second alert gives me a weird number, should I cast it to positive to send it via post?

Comment: @Jonathan - No, if you cast it to positive you mess up a lot of things.  The 2nd alert is simply `11000000 00000000 00000000 00000000` as a _SIGNED_ int.  Your post will understand it properly in just about any language.  If you're really concerned about it (or just seems too weird), restrict yourself to 31 bits.

Comment: thanks, I need to use the 32 flags, will keep it that way as you suggested, ty!

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 0;
var b;
a |= (1 << 31);
b = a
a |= (1 << 30);
b += a
alert(b);
```

In the above case, b will end up as -3221225472.