# How to deal with unsigned numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unsigned-integer

I am having difficult time dealing with unsigned numbers in JavaScript. I would like to perform basic math and bitwise operation on unsigned numbers using JavaScript especially shifting bits. Anyone have suggestions how to deal with unsigned numbers in JavaScript?

Example:
 Shifting 0x40000000 to the left gives you a negative number rather than 0x80000000

Comment: What exactly are your problems?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908492/unsigned-integer-in-javascript ?