# equivalent of INET_ATON() in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

What is the equivalent of INET_ATON() in mongodb? I am using nodejs with mongodb so if a equivalent in nodejs is avaliable than it is good enough.

Comment: You might also want to consider IPv6 support: `inet_pton`

Comment: For nodejs, it looks like you can use this module. https://www.npmjs.com/package/inet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's someone else's solution for converting an IP address from a dotted-decimal string to a 32-bit number:

```
function dot2num(dot) 
{
    var d = dot.split('.');
    return ((((((+d[0])*256)+(+d[1]))*256)+(+d[2]))*256)+(+d[3]);
}
```

From here: [IP-addresses stored as int results in overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105629/ip-addresses-stored-as-int-results-in-overflow)

Answer (score 6):

```
// ip example: 192.168.2.1
function inet_aton(ip){
    // split into octets
    var a = ip.split('.');
    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(4);
    var dv = new DataView(buffer);
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        dv.setUint8(i, a[i]);
    }
    return(dv.getUint32(0));
}

// num example: 3232236033
function inet_ntoa(num){
    var nbuffer = new ArrayBuffer(4);
    var ndv = new DataView(nbuffer);
    ndv.setUint32(0, num);

    var a = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        a[i] = ndv.getUint8(i);
    }
    return a.join('.');
}
```

http://rolfrost.de/ipjs.html

Answer (score 2):

```
function inet_aton(ip){
    var a = new Array();
    a = ip.split('.');
    return((a[0] << 24) >>> 0)  + ((a[1] << 16) >>> 0) + ((a[2] << 8) >>> 0) + (a[3] >>> 0);
}

function inet_ntoa(n){
    var a = ((n >> 24) & 0xFF) >>> 0;
    var b = ((n >> 16) & 0xFF) >>> 0;
    var c = ((n >> 8) & 0xFF) >>> 0;
    var d = (n & 0xFF) >>> 0;
    return(a + "." + b + "." + c + "." + d);
}
```

as of my site see below/above, compatible with older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of the ntoa function in Javascript using typed arrays.

```
function ntoa(ipInt) {
  var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(4);
  var uint8View = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  var uint32View = new Uint32Array(buffer);
  uint32View[0] = ipInt;
  var ipSegments = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < uint8View.length; i ++) {
    ipSegments.push(uint8View[i]);
  }
  return ipSegments.join(".");
}
```