# IP Address storing, sorting, and filtering in MongoDB

Tags: regex, mongodb, filtering, ip-address

I'm trying to figure out how to store IP addresses in a database, particularly MongoDB, so I can easily sort and filter on these addresses.  I've looked over several questions:

[Most efficient way to store IP Address in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542011/most-efficient-way-to-store-ip-address-in-mysql)

[save IP address in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591234/save-ip-address-in-mongodb)

[equivalent of INET_ATON() in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987750/equivalent-of-inet-aton-in-mongodb)

I've implemented an answer from the last question:

```
// ip example: 192.168.2.1
function inet_aton(ip){
    // split into octets
    var a = ip.split('.');
    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(4);
    var dv = new DataView(buffer);
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        dv.setUint8(i, a[i]);
    }
    return(dv.getUint32(0));
}

// num example: 3232236033
function inet_ntoa(num){
    var nbuffer = new ArrayBuffer(4);
    var ndv = new DataView(nbuffer);
    ndv.setUint32(0, num);

    var a = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        a[i] = ndv.getUint8(i);
    }
    return a.join('.');
}
```

This actually works wonderfully.  I store my IPs as ints, and I convert them back to IPs before I send them to my UI, and because I'm storing them as ints, sorting is a freebie.

The problem becomes filtering.  If a user wants to look for an IP that starts with **102.1***, there doesn't seem like a reasonable approach to do this, especially if the user wants to use regexes.  If they search for a full IP, that's no problem, but partial matching is a nuisance.

Does anyone have any insight into this issue?  I'd love to hear any thoughts.

Comment: You mean you don't want to filter on a left substring of inet_ntoa(yourcolumn) because the integers are indexed but not the function(column)?

Comment: you can convert 102.1* to two numbers representing the min and max range and test for everything $lte, $gte those end points.

Comment: @zx81, I'm not sure I understand your question fully.  What I think you're asking is that I've stored the integer values in the database, and I don't call the function before comparing the values?  If so, that is correct.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky, ah interesting.  So what you're saying is, I would search for the lower bound 1711276032, and the upper bound being 1711341568?  I think that would work for that case, but what about something like **.\*102.\***?

Comment: I'm not sure I can think of a valid use case for searching for an IP address other than by a prefix - in any case, you can't use an index there even if you stored them as indexed strings (only left-anchored regex can take advantage of indexes).

Comment: I think you might be right, but I just wanted to cover all of my bases.  I'll try implementing the min and max, and see what the results are.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Turns out we have a requirement for wanting to search on **.\*102.\***, so what I did, even though I don't like it, was created an `ip_converted` field, which is the integer value of the IP, while keeping the original IP string field.  The converted field is used for sorting, and original field is used for filtering.  Rather annoying, but it works for the interim.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can opt for duplication and have two fields in the same document, one with the integer value of your ip address and the other with the string form of it. This would be a one time process during the write. If you have to sort, you can use the integer form and if you have to do any regex searches, you can use the string form of it. All you have to do is to spare the extra space occupied!