# How to get the local IP with NativeScript

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm making an app with NativeScript and I need to get the local IP Adress of the device.
I read in another page that you can access native API's, and they did this:

```
var app = require("application");
var context = android.content.Context;
var wifiManager = app.android.context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
var wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
var ip = wInfo.getIpAddress();
```

I just started with NativeScript so I barely understand what that means.

In the code above, the IP is 251701440, and that's neither the local ip nor the public ip.

Is there any way to get the local IP of the device?

Comment: `251701440` is `15.0.168.192`

Comment: How do you calculate that. And also, it's backwards

Comment: Here you have a function for converting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105629/ip-addresses-stored-as-int-results-in-overflow

Comment: Thanks you very much. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

To get the IP address for Android devices, you could firstly verify the connection type. If it is WiFi, you could use android WiFiManager and in those cases when using mobile data connection - java.net.NetworkInterface.

WiFiManager

```
var context = app.android.context;
var  wifiMgr = context.getSystemService("wifi");
var wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
var ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
var  ipAddress = android.text.format.Formatter.formatIpAddress(ip);
console.log("ip");
console.log(ipAddress);
```

NetworkInterface

```
var en = java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
                 console.log("NetworkInterface");
                 console.log(en)
                 for(var obj in en){
                     var intf = en.nextElement();
                     var enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses();
                     console.log("enumIpAddr");
                     for(var obj2 in enumIpAddr){
                         console.log("obj");
                         if(enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements()){
                             var inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                             if ((!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) && (inetAddress instanceof   java.net.Inet4Address)) {
                                     console.log("return inetAddress.getHostAddress(): "+inetAddress.getHostAddress());
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
```

The second approach with  NetworkInterface is not fully tested and could have some issue with the returning the  address.