# Bit Pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bit

I would like to ask help whether am I doing the right thing or not. You see I am trying to test myself by displaying the bit pattern of a number in the most efficient way as possible. But I'm having trouble on how to display the pattern cause I'm still learning javascript. Here's my code.

```
<script>
    var bitPattern = function(given) {
        for(var i = 1 << 31; i > 0; i = i / 2){
            document.write((given & i) ? 1 : 0);
        }
    };

    var number = prompt("Enter a number to convert: ");

    bitPattern(number);
</script>
```

Comment: what output are you seeing?

Comment: `for (var i = 31; i >= 0; i--) { bit = (given >> i) & 1 }` would probably be a lot more efficient.

Comment: Seriously, wat? Just `num.toString(2)`?

Comment: [Alternatives to document.write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537963/what-are-alternatives-to-document-write)

Comment: Whatever about the most efficient way, this won't work because `<<` returns a negative number. You can use `(1 << 31) >>> 0`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1908655/1469259

Comment: @nicael:  `number.toString(2)` won't work, because `number` is a string.  `(+number).toString(2)` will work.  See http://jsfiddle.net/dnagc0o6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is:

```
var number = prompt("Enter a number to convert: ");
var bitPattern = parseInt(number).toString(2);

document.write(bitPattern);
```

Comment: I tried using this but it would display the original number rather than the bit pattern

Comment: What about now? But I prefer console output over writing results into web page.

Comment: The previous one actually worked. Just forgot to add a "+" to my variable.