# Is it correct to set bit 31 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

When I try to set 31 bit `0 | 1 << 31` I get the following result:

```
console.log(0 | 1 << 31); // -2147483648
```

Which is actualy:

```
console.log((-2147483648).toString(2)) // -10000000000000000000000000000000
```

Is it correct to set 31 bit or should I restrict to `30` to prevent negative values?

Comment: You're setting the 32. bit, not the 31.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer to [`ECMA5`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5) that the bitwise operators and shift operators operate on 32-bit ints, so in that case, the max safe integer is 2^31-1, or 2147483647.

Here is one [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1908655/3011380).

> The `<<` operator is defined as working on signed `32-bit` integers (converted from the native Number storage of double-precision float). So `1<<31` must result in a negative number.
>
> The only JavaScript operator that works using unsigned `32-bit` integers is `>>>`. You can exploit this to convert a signed-integer-in-Number you've been working on with the other bitwise operators to an unsigned-integer-in-Number:
>
> `(1<<31)>>>0`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain do I have mistake in my approach?

Comment: @Erik, I think `sjrd` have one good answer for that, also more details, please refer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908492/unsigned-integer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5):

Most bitwise operations are specified as converting their operands to *signed* 32-bit integers. It is perfectly correct to use bit 31, but yes, you'll get negative values. Usually it doesn't matter if you're doing bitwise operations anyway, since all you (should) care about is the bit pattern, not the decimal value of the number.

If you *do* want a positive value back, you can convert it back with `>>> 0`, because `>>>` is specified to convert its operands to *unsigned* 32-bit integers.

```
console.log((0 | 1 << 31) >>> 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you think about @tkausl comment `You're setting the 32. bit, not the 31` ?

Comment: It's the 32nd bit (counting from 1), but it's bit 31 (counting from 0).

Comment: Thanks for the help!