# (1<<31).toString(16) gives negative -80000000

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 1<<31
var b = 0x80000000
console.log(a, b)
console.log(a.toString(16), b.toString(16))
```

**output**

```
-2147483648 2147483648
-80000000 80000000
```

- How to write an unsigned version of `toString(16)` to get the *expected* result `80000000`?

I suggest that bitwise the `a` variable still holds `10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000`, but `a` and `b` are not equal. Although bitwise they are the same.

Comment: Ah, the joys of numbers in JavaScript. Here's a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1908655/21475

Comment: @Cameron just curious, what was the search query that found it for you? Because I just tried few obvious (for me) queries and did not.

Comment: "JavaScript unsigned int" :-)