# Why left shift is different between PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

In Javascript

```
p = 105874240;
105874240
p << 5;
-906991616
```

But in PHP

```
php > echo $p = 105874240;
105874240
php > echo $p << 5;
3387975680
```

I search some introduce about the different, because Javascript use signed int32.
But I can't find the right solution for it, all not work for me.

Could you please tell me what's going on, and how can I get the same result of Javascript in PHP. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908492/unsigned-integer-in-javascript you need to use the `>>>` operator to convert to 32bit unsigned int in js.

Comment: I mean Javascript result is right, I want PHP get the same result, not change the Javascipt.

Comment: Do you know the difference(s) between signed and unsigned integers and how to tell the OS which one to use and when?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I'd do it.

```
function to32bits($value)
{
    $value = ($value & 0xffffffff);
    if ($value & 0x80000000) $value = -((~$value & 0xffffffff) + 1);
    return $value;
}

$p = 105874240;
echo to32bits($p << 5); // -906991616
```