# Optimising Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was given a quiz and I had gotten the answer wrong and It's been bugging me ever since so I thought I'd ask for your thoughts

I needed to optimise the following function

```
function sumOfEvenNumbers(n) {
    var sum = 0;
    for(let i = 2; i < n;i++){
      if(i % 2 == 0) sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
 }

 console.log(sumOfEvenNumbers(5));
```

I came up with

```
function sumOfEvenNumbers(n) {
    var sum = 0;
    while(--n >= 2) sum += n % 2 == 0? n : 0
    return sum;
}

console.log(sumOfEvenNumbers(5));
```

What other ways were there?

Comment: Would help if you explained the point of the function rather than expecting us to know.

Comment: Note that currently the two functions don't even give identical answers.

Comment: I thought the *name* of the function pretty clearly identified what it did:  Return the sum of all the even numbers less than some limit.

Comment: This question is classic too broad. "Give me every possible other way to do this function". It *might* be okay on [codereview.se], but even there you'd need to define what you're trying to improve.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan would it be possible to move this over or should I delete this question and go over to this section?

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge about that site to say whether this should go over there or not. I'd read their help center and see if it's on topic before doing anything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question, but a math question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit of a math question. The sum appears to be the sum of an [**arithmitic sequence**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) with a common difference of `2`. The sum is:

```
sum = N * (last + first) / 2;
```

where `N` is the number of the numbers in the sequence, `last` is the last number of those numbers, and `first` is the first.

Translated to javascript as:

```
function sumOfEvenNumbers(n) {
    return Math.floor(n / 2) * (n - n % 2 + 2) / 2;
}
```

Because the number of even numbers between `2` and `n` is `Math.floor(n / 2)` and the last even number is `n - n % 2` (`7` would be `7 - 7 % 2 === 6` and `8` would be `8 - 8 % 2 === 8`). and the first is `2`.

Comment: Why Math.floor in one half, and n-n%2 in the other?

Comment: @MartinBonner Because if `n` is `15` then `Math.floor(n / 2)` will be `7` and `n - n % 2` will be `14`.

Comment: @ibrahim mahir I myself did not get this solution for Martin Bonner's exact same reason

Answer (score 3):

Sum of n numbers:

```
var sum = (n * (n+1)) / 2;
```

Sum of n even numbers:

```
var m = Math.floor(n/2);
var sum = 2 * (m * (m+1) /2);
```

Comment: Isn't `2 * (m * (m+1) / 2)` exactly the same as `m * (m+1)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can compute these sums using an arithmetic sum formula in constant time:

```js
// Return sum of positive even numbers < n:
function sumOfEvenNumbers(n) {
  n = (n - 1) >> 1;
  return n * (n + 1);
}

// Example:
console.log(sumOfEvenNumbers(5));
```

Above computation avoids modulo and division operators which consume more CPU cycles than multiplication, addition and bit-shifting. Pay attention to the [limited range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908492/unsigned-integer-in-javascript) of the bit-shifting operator `>>` though.

See e.g. http://oeis.org/A002378 for this and other formulas leading to the same result.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to eliminate the test in the loop:

```
function sumOfEvenNumbers(n) {
   var sum = 0;
   var halfN= Math.floor(n/2);
   for(let i = 1; i < n/2;i++) {
      sum += i;
   }
   return sum * 2;
}
```

Then we can observe that is just calculating the sum of all the integers *less* than a limit - and there is a formula for that (but actually formula is for *less-equal* a limit).

```
function sumOfEvenNumbers(n) {
   var halfNm1= Math.floor(n/2)-1;
   var sum = halfNm1 * (halfNm1+1) / 2;
   return sum * 2;
}
```

And then eliminate the division and multiplication and the unnecessary addition and subtraction:

```
function sumOfEvenNumbers(n) {
   var halfN= Math.floor(n/2);
   return (halfN-1) * halfN;
}
```

Comment: Sum of even numbers is the OP problem I think  ;)

Comment: @Tushar I changed the function name while he was editing

Comment: OK, so were both downvotes for the name not matching the new name?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution computes in linear (O(N)) time.

If you use a mathematical solution, you can compute it in O(1) time:

```
function sum(n) {
  let half = Math.ceil(n/2)
  return half * (half + 1)
}
```

Comment: where is variable `w` from?

Comment: Typo - should be 2.

Comment: Given an argument of 2, the original would return 0.  You return 2.  I *hate* off-by-one errors.

Comment: Updated to use `Math.ceil` instead.

Comment: @bcherny : Using `Math.ceil` doesn't fix it.  An input of 2 *still* returns 2 (rather than 0).

Answer (score 0):

Because the question is tagged ecmascript-6 :)

```js
const sumEven = x => [...Array(x + 1).keys()].reduce((a, b) => b % 2 === 0 ? a + b : a, 0);

// set max number

console.log(sumEven(10));
```